# Quick way for proving $\Gamma(z) \neq 0$ for $z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Using the equation $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac \pi {\sin \pi z}$, this is easy to show that $\Gamma(z)$ never vanishes on $\mathbb C$.

Is there shorter way for showing $\Gamma$ is not zero ?

Comment: A product is zero iff a factor is zero.

Comment: I don't understand, of course in $\mathbb C$ a product is zero if and only if a factor is zero. But the functionnal equation is a bit long to show : I was wondering if there is shorter proof (only for the definition) that $\Gamma$ is not zero, this is my question.

Comment: That depends on the definition ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going back to [Gauss](http://www.archive.org/stream/briefwechselzwi00berlgoog#page/n183/mode/2up), we use the definition
$$ \Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^x}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n))}$$
for $x\in \Bbb C\setminus\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$. From this we obtain 
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac1z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-1}e^{x\ln\frac{n+1}n}. $$
The very fact that this converges in the sense of convergent infinite products tells us that $\Gamma(z)\ne 0$ except possibly at non-positive integers. The rest follows from $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$.